# How to solve Geoserver Jetty "Module not found ssl" error?

Tags: windows, ssl, https, jetty, geoserver

My objective, is to configure the Jetty in such a way that it enables HTTPS request for Geoserver.

To be a bit specific, I am downloading the Geoserver Windows Installer.
As tested both version 2.9-RC1 and 2.10.2, they throw the warning

`"Module not found [ssl]"` as soon as it is started.
[image]

Jetty version: 9.2.13.v20150730

I am referring to the [info](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html#configuring-sslcontextfactory) here to try setup the simplest test (self-signed) for the jetty, but still no luck.

What I did:

1. Use Keytool create a self-signed keystore
2. Replace the keystore generated from 1) to directory etc/keystore
3. Edit the `jetty-ssl.xml`, replace the password (attribute `default`) with mine
4. Edit the file `start.ini`, add `--module=https`, `jetty.secure.port=8443`
5. Launch the batch file.

[image]

What did i miss?

P.S.: Geoserver works perfectly in HTTP. This post is asking about configuration for HTTPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `https` module has a dependency on the `ssl` module. The error is stating it cannot find `ssl.mod` in the `${jetty.home}/modules` (or, depending on your config, `${jetty.base}/modules`) directory.

The `ssl` module comes standard as part of the Jetty distribution so it has either been deleted, moved or renamed as part of your implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Here are the steps to enable jetty to run geoserver on https, port:8443

• Configuring Jetty for SSL

follow this link to create ssl certificate and keystore. https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.1.5.v20140505/configuring-ssl.html

2. Now open jetty-ssl.xml file present in Geoserver/etc folder and replace the KeyStorePassword, KeyManagerPassword, TrustStorePassword with the new password which is created while creating keystore.
3. Open & check jetty.xml file in same folder, on which port https will run.

• Add new Keystore in Geoserver

4. Copy the created keystore file and replace with the existing available in etc folder of geoserver ex: C:\GeoServer\etc.
5. Now check if ssl.mod file is present in modules folder or not, ex: C:\GeoServer\modules.
6. If present, then open the file and replace the password in jetty.keystore.password, jetty.keymanager.password and jetty.truststore.password with the new password. Otherwise download it from “http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.2.13.v20150730/jetty-distribution-9.2.13.v20150730.tar.gz.

NOTE : Please make sure password entered should be same as in jetty-ssl.xml.

7. Open start.ini file present in C:\GeoServer folder add  --module =ssl, --module=https and jetty.secure.port=8443 (if https is running on Port 8443.
8. Run geoserver, enter url https://localhost:8443/geoserver (assuming geoserver on local system).

Answer (score 1):

For Geoserver 2.12.1, I manually installed "ssl.mod" from [jetty-distribution-9.2.13.v20150730.tar.gz](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.2.13.v20150730/jetty-distribution-9.2.13.v20150730.tar.gz) in Geoserver's etc/modules directory.  Then the warning message didn't occur again in the log.

Answer (score 0):

1. remember to add `--module=ssl` to `start.ini`
2. complete password and `keystore/truststore` location in `jetty-ssl`
3. port in `jetty-https` default `443`
4. port in `jetty xml` can stay at default `8443`

open ssl mod in a text editor and comment out the `keystore` under the [files] tag
`ini-template tag --jetty` secure port can stay at 8443
Comment out anything that refers to jetty keystore as these are set in jetty-ssl

open https mod and change https port to 443, restart `geoserver`.
Geoserver should now run over jetty `https://` with no port number.